# ajax double request on change dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, ajax

have four drop down menus and this jQuery code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

$('.ffilter').on('change', function(e) {
    var fbrand = $('#fbrand').val();
    var ftyp = $('#ftyp').val();
    var fmaterial = $('#fmaterial').val();
    var fstatus = $('#fstatus').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'application/inc/fun.filter.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { varb: fbrand, vtyp: ftyp, vmat: fmaterial, vsta: fstatus },
      success: function(data, status) {
           $('.productoverview').html(data);
           $("img").unveil();
      }
    })
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

});

The function works well, but it always gives two request if the dropDown Menus has changes.

Any ideas why this happens?

Thanks for help
thomas

Comment: Maybe setting `e.preventDefault();` at the beginning?

Comment: can we see your html?

Comment: unfortunately i can't show any html because client-site isn't live yet. But we have 4 dd like this: <select id="ftyp" class="fselect ffilter" name="ftyp"><option value="">Typ/Geschlecht</option><option value="male">Herren</option><option value="female">Frauen</option><option value="unisex">Unisex</option></select>